# How can I hydrate trees in the desert?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to grow a perfect jungle tree in the desert. I tried to grow it with:

```
S S S
S D S
S S S
```

schema (s = sand, d = dirt) and bonemeal and it grows correctly but is seems rotten or dry.
Is there any way to convert the existing one into an hydrated one? how can I grow hydrate trees in the desert?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It’s not possible (without a mod), because the color of leaves (and grass and water) is defined by the biome it is in. Since you are planting the tree in a desert biome, the tree's leaves have desert leaves colors.

Even if you collect leaves from green trees with shears, they will appear brown when you place them in the desert.

Answer (score 0):

As Cedi correctly noted, the shading of the leaves is based on the biome. There are two ways to change the local biome, but both involve additional programs:

### Modding the game

A mod like [WorldEdit](http://www.sk89q.com/projects/worldedit/) can change biomes of the selected area. The relevant commands are:

- `/biome` Get the biometype you are standing in.
- `/biomelist` List the available biome types
- `//setbiome [-p] <biome type>` Set the selected area to the specified biome type.
  The -p flag changes the block (column) you are standing in.

Source: [WorldEdit command reference](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Reference)

Video tutorial by "Flexo13"

### Editing the world

An external world editor like [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-now-open-source/) can set biomes on any part of the map using, for example SethBling's [SetBiome filter](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1220405-setbiome-filter-for-mcedit-download-now/). The forum post I linked also contains a video tutorial how to do it:

Comment: As a side note: The WorldEdit biome commands weren't implemented yet when the question was originally asked (and answered), so I think it's of value to provide a new, updated answer now that they do and work reliably.

Answer (score -3):

Try placing water around the sides of the tree, and shading it.